# Print a solid colored square with Ruby

Tags: ruby, trello, colorize

I'm working on modifying Brett Weaver's [Trello CLI](https://github.com/brettweavnet/trello_cli) ruby-based utility to include information from a Trello card object, namely the label colors associated with that card.  Right now, I can do something like the following to iterate through the labels on each card:

```
list_cards.each_with_index do |card, i|

  puts "#{i+1} #{card.name}"

    card.labels.each do |label|
      puts "(#{label.name})"
    end
end
```

Rather than printing the `label.name` attribute, I would prefer to print a solid colored square that corresponds to the `label.color` attribute.  An example of this can be seen in another library [seen here](https://raw.github.com/blangel/wrk/master/docs/img/trello-id.png).  I've read about using the [colorize](http://colorize.rubyforge.org/files/README_txt.html) library to get the color, but first I can't figure out how to get it to print a color dynamically rather than explicitly and second, I can't figure out how I would print a square.  Additionally, the colorize gem doesn't have the range of colors that are needed from Trello (like orange or purple).

Comment: @CarySwoveland That was extraneous; a result of me not being a ruby native and just copying the structure of the outside block. Editted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the `colorize` gem, all you need to do is print two spaces on a background color, like:

```
puts "  ".colorize(background: :blue)
```

to display a blue square.

Comment: But how would I tell it to print a color using the `label.color` attribute, which is a string (i.e. `"blue"`).

Comment: `puts "  ".colorize(background: label.color.to_sym)` should work if your color names are not too foreign.

Comment: But what about colors that are not included with colorize? Like orange or purple?

Comment: I added case statements for orange and purple to change them to colorize-compatible colors (realizing that no matter what I did, the terminal would not output certain colors.  This worked great.  Thanks!

Comment: The VT100 Terminal Emulator has basic support for the 8 colors as mentioned in [`colorize`](https://github.com/fazibear/colorize/blob/master/lib/colorize.rb).